# Python/openpyxl script to detect cell value and print output from cells next to it

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, juniper

I am having issues creating a script using openpyxl - in short what this script is meant to do is read an excel sheets cell value and print CLI commands for Juniper CLI.

My problem is i want to automate the process of the script finding specific rows "rule name" and printing the following columns after (ie source addresses/destination addresses)

As you can see from the script below my current work around is inputting the row number manually but if i can automate it by detecting specific convention names such as "StackOverflow 1, StackOverflow 2" and printing another set of commands for rule 2 that would be amazing i am just unsure on how to do it.

Is anyone able to help.

```
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook(input('Workbook name: '), data_only=True) 

ws = wb["Sheet name"]

rownumber = int(input('Row Number Of Rule: '))

name = (ws.cell(row=rownumber, column=1).value)
source = (ws.cell(row=rownumber, column=4).value) 
destination = (ws.cell(row=rownumber, column=5).value)
port = (ws.cell(row=rownumber, column=6).value) 
description = (ws.cell(row=rownumber, column=10).value)
fromzone = (ws.cell(row=rownumber, column=2).value)
tozone = (ws.cell(row=rownumber, column=3).value)

print ('set logical-systems security policies from-zone %s to-zone %s policy %s match source-address %s' %(fromzone,tozone,name,source))
print ('set logical-systems security policies from-zone %s to-zone %s policy %s match destination-address %s' %(fromzone,tozone,name,destination))
print ('set logical-systems security policies from-zone %s to-zone %s policy %s match application %s' %(fromzone,tozone,name,port))
print ('set logical-systems security policies from-zone %s to-zone %s policy %s description %s' %(fromzone,tozone,name,description))
print ('set logical-systems security policies from-zone %s to-zone %s policy %s then permit' %(fromzone,tozone,name))
print ('set logical-systems security policies from-zone %s to-zone %s policy %s then log session-init' %(fromzone,tozone,name))
```

Comment: I think you need to tell us more about the rules. It should be fairly easy to search a worksheet for a cell containing a relevant value.